# Carousel doesn't show on my website

Tags: html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I try run carousel on my website: marekzurek.hekko24.pl , under "Pracuję z najlepszymi" Code looks fine but carousel doesn't show. Could you take a look at this?

Comment: Are you talking about the carousel for `.testimonial-list`? If so, seems to be working for me.

Comment: No, There should be carousel under "Pracuję z najlepszymi" as well.

Comment: where are you initializing that? You're only initializing `.testimonial-list` and `.blog-slider` here http://marekzurek.hekko24.pl/assets/js/scripts.js

Comment: @MichaelCoker  
I'm newbie. Could you please tell me how should I initialize it?

Comment: You don't have any code in the "Pracuję z najlepszymi" section, so there is nothing to initialize. But you structure a bunch of HTML that owl can recognize then initialize it the same way you do `.testimonial-list` and `.blog-slider` in that script file.